# Ignore first element with XPATH

Tags: python, xpath

I need to get only text from the following structure, however, ignoring the first element, which would be the `<span>SIGNIFICADO: </span>` tag

```
<p class="p1">
 <span>SIGNIFICADO: </span>
 <strong>
    <a href="www.site.com">Text Link</a>
</strong> 

Some text Some text Some text

</p>
```

Currently I do it like this: `p1=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//p[@class="p1"]').text`

And if I put this xpath: `//p[@class="p1"]/text()`

Text that is inside the `<a>` tag is ignored.

How can I get all the text except the first one that is inside `<span>` ??

Answer (score 0):

To omit text of and before the first element, you can use

```
//p[@class="p1"]//text()[preceding::*]
```

This selects all text nodes that have at least one preceding element(here: `<span>`. Disadvantage is that this also discards text *between* the `<p>` element and the `<span>` element.

Comment: It didn't work like I need it to. It got all 3 texts but I need to ignore the first one which is inside <span></span>

Comment: I tested the expression, but not with Python. Maybe Python has some peculiar restrictions.